# if condition doesn't return as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a piece of code which finds the minimum of a variable (RSS3) only when all the elements of a list (guess3) are > 0. I've done:

```
 if RSS3_min < RSS3_fin and (all(guess3[q]) > 0 for q in range(len(guess3))):
     RSS3_fin = RSS3_min
     guess3_fin = guess3
     print i,j,k, 'RSS3 = ',RSS3_fin, 'guess3 = ', guess3
```

The output looks like:

```
0 1 2 RSS3 =  152.470584348 guess3 =  [  1.03993316e-18  -4.21309327e-21   3.91958921e-23]
0 1 3 RSS3 =  138.828305634 guess3 =  [ -9.72979812e-18   2.45455199e-20   9.91015993e-17]
0 2 6 RSS3 =  110.971076196 guess3 =  [  2.51690683e-18   6.50243486e-23  -1.64840584e-18]
0 2 12 RSS3 =  110.167564411 guess3 =  [  1.67526232e-18   6.93897310e-23  -9.25020238e-19]
```

which means that the second piece of my `if` condition isn't satisfied. Where am I wrong? Please, consider that I'm really new to python, so keep things simple... Thanks!

Comment: What about your output suggests to you that the second piece of the `if`isn't satisfied? What output are you expecting to get instead?

Comment: `all(guess3[q])  > 0` does not do what you think, that will only be True if you have no falsey value in whatever `guess3[q])` is and then only because `True > 0`

Comment: Hint: what's a difference between: `(all(g) > 0 for g in guess3)` and `all(g>0 for g in guess3)`?

Comment: OK, with the aid of the alecxe's answer i think I've understood. I hope. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closing parenthesis is not in the right place, fix it:

```
if RSS3_min < RSS3_fin and all(guess3[q] > 0 for q in range(len(guess3))):
```

Note that, since this is Python, you can loop over the items in the list directly:

```
if RSS3_min < RSS3_fin and all(item > 0 for item in guess3):
```

Comment: Or just `all(q > 0 for q in guess3)`